# how to select collection type navigation property's value

Tags: linq, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have 3 tables, team(id,name) player(id,teamid,name) playerdetail(id,playerid,height,weight), the relationship between team and player is one to many, the relationship between player and playerdetail is one to one.

I want to use eager loading to load all the information and print out the name of players who is higher than 2 meters.

I have write the code below,

```
using (var context = new TestEntities())
            {
                var query = from t in context.Teams.Include("Players.PlayerDetails") select t;
                foreach (var v in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(v.Players.Any(x => x.PlayerDetails.Any(y => y.Height > 200)));
                }
                Console.Read();
            }
```

It prints out only true and false, how can I modify it and make it print out the name of player?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just query the players through `context.Players` like below?

```
        using (var context = new TestEntities())
        {
            var query = context.Players.Include("Team").Include("PlayerDetails")
                           .Where(p => p.Height > 200);
            foreach (var v in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.Name);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```